# EF Core - Navigation Property loaded from SQL view

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-core-2.2

I have the following entities:

```
    public class Animal
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Current Animal Status
        /// </summary>
        public virtual AnimalStatus CurrentAnimalStatus
        {
            get { return AnimalStatuses.OrderByDescending(x => x.VersionNo).First(); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// List of all Animal Statuses
        /// </summary>
        public virtual ICollection<AnimalStatus> AnimalStatuses { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// List of all Animal Operations
        /// </summary>
        public virtual ICollection<AnimalOperation> AnimalOperations { get; set; }
    }
```

and

```
    public class AnimalStatus
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int VersionNo { get; set; }

        public int BloodCount { get; set; }

        public int AnimalId { get; set; }

        public virtual Animal Animal { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm only ever interested in the most recent `AnimalStatus` so would like to use a View to populate just the `CurrentAnimalStatus` property and remove the need for `ICollection<AnimalStatus>`.  The rest of the `Animal` entity should be populated by EF core.

Currently the `AnimalStatus` table holds 300,000 records so is very slow using EF Core with

```
_dbContext.Animal.Include(x => x.AnimalStatus);
```

Is it possible in EF Core to have a navigation property on an entity be populated from a SQL view ?

```
                CREATE VIEW [dbo].[CurrentAnimalStatusView]
                AS
                    WITH ANIMAL_EVENTS_CTE AS
                    (
                        SELECT
                            AnimalId,
                            BloodCount,
                            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AnimalId ORDER BY VersionNo DESC) AS RowNumber --RowNumber = 1 indicates the latest status
                        FROM
                            AnimalBloodTests
                    )
                    SELECT
                        AnimalId,
                        BloodCount
                    FROM
                        ANIMAL_EVENTS_CTE cte
                    WHERE
                        RowNumber = 1 --Only interested in latest status for each AnimalId
```

Comment: Views and ORMs generally aren't worth it, IMO. Generally no performance gains and you loose most of the benefits if the ORM. What's the IQueryable query look like? As I don't see a join to AnimalStatus in your view, which is what your EF query does.

Comment: One improvement might be an index on _VersionNo_.
Another way is creating a projection while querying the animals and just loading the relevant properties and only the latest status.

Answer (score -3):

You can create a model for your view and map it to Dbset.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder.Entity<CurrentAnimalStatus>(eb =>
    {
      eb.HasNoKey();
      eb.ToView("CurrentAnimalStatusView");
    });
  base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error like this: `the navigation '' cannot be added because it targets the keyless entity type 'MyView'. Navigations can only target entity types with keys.`